# Python bs4: How to Repeat “For” Loop with a Different Scraped Page if a Certain Condition is Met?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a `for` loop where once it gets to the last `search_result` attribute in the scraped page, it will repeat the loop but with the data of a new scraped web page.

After the `for` loop gets to the last attribute, it will look for a link on the web page and it will repeat the loop with the new scraped web page.

I have written the code below but the loop doesn't repeat itself with the new scraped page that it got from a link from the original web page.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

for search_result in soup.find_all(attrs={"search-result-index":True}):
    print(search_result.name.text)

    # if last search result, get link to new web page and repeat loop for the new web page.
    if search_result == soup.find_all(attrs={"search-result-index":True})[-1]:
        page = requests.get(soup.select_one('li.a-last [href]')['href'], headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

Do you have any ideas about how to do it?

Comment: Can you contain the original for loop in a function, with the html (or bs4 page object) as a parameter, then call the function again with the new page? You should read this page about recursion: https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/

Comment: please share the link you're trying to scrape, and the search criteria.

Comment: turn it into a function then you can just loop the function using `while True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this??

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}


def func_go(URL):
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    for search_result in soup.find_all(attrs={"search-result-index":True}):
        print(search_result.name.text)

        if search_result == soup.find_all(attrs={"search-result-index":True})[-1]:
            URL = soup.select_one('li.a-last [href]')['href']
            func_go(URL)




func_go('www.example.com')
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!